# javascript object with array prototype

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

Recently, I read an article that have the following lines

```
var obj = {};
Array.prototype.push.call(obj, 'aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc');
console.log(obj);
{0: "aaa", 1: "bbb", 2: "ccc", length: 3}
```

I know it tries to use obj as the context and passing the rest as the arguments. Before, I only used to push each item into an array. I am curious what is the logic behind this implementation. How it set index as each key of the value and why 'length' is automatically add to the object as well? thanks

Comment: Because that's how `push` works: http://es5.github.io/#x15.4.4.7

Comment: In fact, many Array methods are ... 'intentionally generic and do not require that their `this` value be an Array object', quoting the same doc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Because that's how `push` works](http://es5.github.io/#x15.4.4.7). Most array methods are intentionally generic so they can be applied to other objects, not only arrays.

> When the push method is called with zero or more arguments item1,item2, etc., the following steps are taken:
>
> 1. Let *O* be the result of calling [ToObject](http://es5.github.io/#x9.9) passing the `this` value as the argument.

This just ensures that `this` is an object: `var O = Object(this);`

> 2. Let *lenVal* be the result of calling the [[Get]] internal method of *O* with argument "length".

`var lenVal = O.length;`. `lenVal` will be `undefined` in our case, since the object doesn't have a `length` property.

> 3. Let *n* be [ToUint32](http://es5.github.io/#x9.6)(*lenVal*).

Converts `lenVal` to a number and assigns the result to `n`. `undefined` will be converted to `0`.

> 4. Let *items* be an internal List whose elements are, in left to right order, the arguments that were passed to this function invocation.

Basically `var items = arguments;`.

> 5. Repeat, while *items* is not empty
>
>    - Remove the first element from *items* and let *E* be the value of the element.
>    - Call the [[Put]] internal method of *O* with arguments [ToString](http://es5.github.io/#x9.8)(*n*), *E*, and `true`.
>    - Increase n by 1.

This simply iterates over all entries in `items`, assigns `O[String(n)] = E;` and `n += 1`. This is where each argument you pass to push is assigned to the object!

> 6. Call the [[Put]] internal method of *O* with arguments "length", *n*, and `true`.

Sets `length` to `n`: `O.length = n;`. This is where `length` is set!

> 7. Return *n*.

Comment: that is a really detailed explanation. Your comment is more readable than ECMA5 instruction. thanks a lot